# deploy a java EE application on a live server

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, tomcat, web-deployment

I've just finished developing a java ee application with tomcat and  spring boot and angularjs and mysql on localhost, please can any body help how to deploy this app to run on live server and what are the changes must be done before generate the war ( i meant the porte 8080 and mysql porte) because finally i want tu run my app on http://myserver.com/myapp/  instead of http://myserver.com:8080/myapp/

Comment: copy and paste the war file under tomcat/webapp if you want to do it manually

Comment: Port 8080 won't be available to anyone behind a firewall.  You're better off if your app listens on port 80.  What live server?  Are you asking how to deploy on AWS or some other cloud service?

Comment: now i have the application in my own laptop,and i want to move it to the the server in the company where i'm working, i dont know what should i do,if i have to move eclipse and everything else to the server to get things done i dont know what i have to do, please help!!!!

Comment: You must change tomcat port from `8080` to `80`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spring Boot, don't use the war option. Build a fat jar instead. That's the more common way of deploying Sprint Boot and it will save you an incredible amount of pain like this. For example, your complaint about ports is (going on memory) solved liked this:

`java -Dserver.port=80 -jar some-service.jar`

or

`export SERVER_PORT=80
java -jar some-service.jar`

FWIW, Spring Boot bundles Tomcat with the fat jar.

Comment: now i have the application in my own laptop,and i want to move it to the the server in the company where i'm working, i dont know what should i do,if i have to move eclipse and everything else to the server to get things done i dont know what i have to do, please help!!!!

Comment: You don't have to move Eclipse. You need to write the project so that its configuration is portable between your laptop and the server. That is not hard. You just avoid hard-coding environment-specific details like database configuration details into your app.

Comment: this is the problem i hard-code database url in the configuration file and also i hard-code the urls in angularjs app, like this: 'http://localhost:8080/toto/titi', tell me pleast what are the changes which i have to do before deploying this app